# text adjustment in table

Tags: tables

[image][image]Hello I put the text in the table but I need to set when the sentence finish the number is go to the next line, not appear after the previous text. see the red highlight, I want the numbers start in new line. also when I add the bold font to the caption it shows error.

[image: see the red highlight, I want the numbers start in new line.]

```
\begin{center}
 %\begin{table}[h!]
 % \bigskip
     \begin{longtable}{ |p{2.1cm} | p{2.5cm} | p{2.4cm} |  p{2.1cm} |  p{2.2cm} | p{2.2cm} |}
     \caption{Comparison Between the Wormhole Attacks } 
     \tabularnewline
     \hline
     Wormhole types & Encapsulation & Out of Band & High Power & Packet Relay & Protocol Deviations \tabularnewline \hline



      Advantages  & 1- there is a smaller probability of RREQ being discarded than other RREQs which are repeatedly received by intermediate nodes. 2- RREQ packet arriving to destination, does not keep middle nodes as hops, and then it appears to have passed through minimum number of hops. & 1- Control packet arrives faster due to no process from middle nodes 2- Less probability of discarding compare to RREQs which are repeatedly received by middle nodes. 3- Control packets arrive at destination, middle nodes not use as hops, pass through less number of hops & 1- Control packets arrive faster 2- Less probability of discarding compare to RREQs which are repeatedly received by middle nodes. 3- Control packets arrive at destination, middle nodes not use as hops, pass through less number of hops    & 1- Two nodes think they are neighbors although they are not, and every RREQ to be sent to neighbors will arrive to relay nodes invisibility. 2- Control packet seems to arrive using minimum number of hops   & control packet arrives faster  \tabularnewline[.5ex] \hline


     \end{longtable}
 %    \end{table}
 \end{center}
```

Comment: Have you tried inserting `\par` before `2-`, `3-`, etc?

Comment: yes I use it before but also need to have better format for table as text is not shown well.

Answer (score 1):

Your table is too wide if used in a standard `article`. That's why I put it in a landscape. In future questions, please provide a real MWE.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcounter{temp}
\newcommand{\first}{\setcounter{temp}{1}\thetemp- }
\newcommand{\following}{\stepcounter{temp}\par\thetemp- }

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{center}
        \captionof{table}{Comparison Between the Wormhole Attacks}
        \begin{longtable}{|p{1.8cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.5cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.4cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.1cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.2cm}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.2cm}|} 
            \hline
            \textbf{Wormhole types} & \textbf{Encapsulation} & \textbf{Out of Band} & \textbf{High Power} & \textbf{Packet Relay} & \textbf{Protocol Deviations} \\\hline      
            Advantages  
            & \first there is a smaller probability of RREQ being discarded than other RREQs which are repeatedly received by intermediate nodes.
                \following RREQ packet arriving to destination, does not keep middle nodes as hops, and then it appears to have passed through minimum number of hops. 
            & \first Control packet arrives faster due to no process from middle nodes
                \following Less probability of discarding compare to RREQs which are repeatedly received by middle nodes.
                \following Control packets arrive at destination, middle nodes not use as hops, pass through less number of hops 
            & \first Control packets arrive faster
                \following Less probability of discarding compare to RREQs which are repeatedly received by middle nodes.
                \following Control packets arrive at destination, middle nodes not use as hops, pass through less number of hops    
            & \first Two nodes think they are neighbors although they are not, and every RREQ to be sent to neighbors will arrive to relay nodes invisibility.
                \following Control packet seems to arrive using minimum number of hops   
            & control packet arrives faster \\\hline        
        \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, but I face error when do it and also some page are just showing 1 line only and the rest page is empty.

Comment: @mehdi Sorry, but this comment is very unclear. What error? My MWE above compiles just fine. Please minimize your document until you find the error, try to fix it, and come back to this site if you are not able to. Without specific information, we are just guessing around.

Comment: I do not know why it shows error and I'm beginner in leaning Latex. sorry if face misunderstanding.

Comment: the error is related to this line:   \captionof{table}{Comparison Between the Wormhole Attacks}  it say undefined control sequence \captionof

Comment: @mehdi load the package `caption`

Comment: I done but the header of table is in one page and the next row in another page. see the above picture.

Comment: @mehdi You have to start with my MWE and then add your original stuff. Like this, you will see directly when what is happening why. Why do you even need a `longtable`? Use a `tabular` instead. I guess (yes guess, because we have no info) that you have some `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}` or alike in your preamble. This causes the huge line distance in your picture.

Comment: I use longtable as the part I put is just 1 page out of 5 page. already it solve by your help. thanks